# How to make different register page in Laravel using Auth()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I m new in using Laravel.

I have used "$php artisan auth" for authorization and I have added a role table to the system. 
Now I want to make different register pages for my every user and I m having issues with how to manage routes for different pages with role id.

for eg., I want to StudentRegister.blade.php page. In this page, a user gets register with role id 1
and 
similarly in TeacherRegister.blade.php User gets register in a database by role id 2.

This is my code for auth() of the user register

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>




                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I hope you get idea from this video https://devmarketer.io/learn/setting-multi-authentication-laravel-5-4-part-1/

Comment: What issues do you have? It's not clear to me from reading your question.I get what your end-goal is, but not what's happening now.

Comment: @Stormhammer   
I 'm sorry for inconvenience the problem I m facing is that I m new and I am not aware that how to write the syntax of that role_id will be 1 or something else on this  specific page.

Comment: @ashokpoudel thanku but I have seen this video before and in this video it is told that there will be different classes of teacher and student while I m making only one user class and I want some fields filled and some nulled on that specific page

Comment: Could you also post the code of the controller that handles the registration form?

Comment: Also post your Routes and make sure you are directing to your new blade, or is that the old blade and you jsut changed the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095255/refrence-to-old-post